# Automatically determine needed libraries / g++ -MM analog for libraries?

Tags: c++, build, g++

The question title sums up what I am looking for, I will try to explain by mentioning my use case.

I create many very small projects / libraries that often depend on all or some libraries of other projects. When first learning C++ I very quickly opted to write my own Makefiles instead of using an IDE to generate them because these generated Makefiles were hard to understand and seemed to include many unnecessary things.
However when writing the Makefiles for each project and trying to determine and link all dependencies I got increasingly sceptical why I am doing this manually every time..

So ideally I am looking for something that simply "looks for" and automatically links all required dependencies, when given the source file and a list of include and library directories. This seems reasonably simple to do, yet I searched many times for a solution and could not find anything.

I am aware there are tools like CMake, autotools, .. (?) and have used them (very) few times to compile other code but they seemed just as overcomplicated/user-unfriendly to use if not more than the IDE option.

Initially to save time I just statically linked **all** existing libraries from each project that has dependencies to each executable even if only some of them were needed. This works but it is clearly not optimal, it also leads to incomprehensible dependencies when the list of libraries grows.

A while ago I opted to write a short script to do part of what I want, it reads a source file, strips comments, and then looks for .hh and .o/.so/.a files in the list of supplied include and library directories. However it simply directly reads #include directives and is also not recursive, meaning if a header that is included implicitly has a separate dependency it is not found.

To get to the question: is it not an "easy" job to generate Make rules in this way? I can likely extend my script to be recursive, but I think simply reading #include directives may lead to problems? Does it? Also, g++ (which is what I am using) has an option -MM to do exactly what I want, but only for headers. Is there an analog option / way that does exactly this, but outputs used libraries instead of headers?

---

### Edit

After a good comment let me add what I did not make too clear:
My starting point is that have the source file, the location of all include dirs, the location of all library dirs **and** that a "brute force" compilation where **all** libraries and include dirs are passed to the compiler call, is successfull. I.e.

```
g++ -o program program.cc -I"paths/to" -I"all/existing" -I"include/dirs" -L"paths/to" -L"all/existing" -L"library/dirs" -o:names_of.o -o:all_existing.o -o:library_files.o
```

compiles program successfully. Then, since the linking and name resolution was already successful, it should be clear internally which libraries are needed and which are not. What I want is an output of only these needed libraries (though I guess this might require compling a second time, after the first one with all libs).

Comment: Given a  function call `f(42)` how do I know which `f` is being called, and where its implementation might be?

Comment: with cmake you can `foreach` your library do `add_subdirectory(the_library EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` and then just `target_add_library(your_program library1 library2 library3)`. How can you get simpler than that? You want to find a library (the libraries include path and sources) from the `#include` statements in your code? Like you do `#include <lib1.h>` and your script should auto add `lib1.h` include path to the source and auto link with `lib1` library?

Comment: _@Shiwayari_ You probably should add which exact build system  you're using. [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) is widely used.

Comment: @NeilButterworth this is why I suspect simply reading #include directives does not do the job. However the libraries I write do not have overlapping names, so it should be possible given include/lib dirs to traverse each header, find the corresponding lib with that name, determine if that lib is used in the code (this is the hard part..?) and if yes then link it. Am i missing something else?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ i am using gnu-make with self written Makefiles, nothing else

Comment: @Shiwayari I don't think it's possible simply to deduce what you need from the generated object files or archives.

Comment: Just for fun, I did [this](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/tmp/cmake_autodependencies). Assuming a certain library and directory structure, for each `#include` file inside each source files, I inferred with what this source file should link with and which include path should be added to compile this file. Works kind of - some assumptions are needed, but maybe this could be more extendable.